# yield return foreach in linq

Tags: linq, foreach, return, yield

Problem:
Can any one tell me how to return value in linq.
I want to return a collection of RadToolBarButtons and assigning them their values at the time of creation.

Code:
I tried in two ways:

```
IEnumerable<RadToolBarButton> collection = ContextMenuColumn.ToList()
      .ForEach(x => yield return new RadToolBarButton() { Value = x });
```

Error   11  Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

```
IEnumerable<RadToolBarButton> collection =
    ContextMenuColumn.SelectMany<string,IEnumerable<RadToolBarButton>>(
       x => new RadToolBarButton() { Value = x });
```

Error   11  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Telerik.Web.UI.RadToolBarButton' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `Select` instead of `ForEach`, it does what you are looking for.

```
IEnumerable<RadToolBarButton> collection = ContextMenuColumn.ToList()
  .Select(x => new RadToolBarButton { Value = x });
```

I am not sure if the inner `ToList` is necessary, you may be able to get away with a `Cast<T>` instead of *materializing* the intermediate list.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Select` instead of `ForEach`, it will do the `yield return` for you